# SVN Error - Catch-22

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I tried to check out our project from my group's SVN repository on a new computer, but ended up in a catch-22 situation.  It works fine for a while, then gets to a certain file it can't move.

```
Can't move "...\Simfile\tempfile.3.tmp" to "...\Simfile\tempfile.2.tmp": 
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Also, there is a file called "tempfile.tmp" in that same directory.

When I try to update further, it says that the folder is locked and to run the Clean Up function.  When I try to run the Clean Up function, it says that one of the files in the directory is not under version control.  When I try performing either "Tortoise SVN -> Add" or "Tortoise SVN -> Delete and Add to Ignore List," it tells me that the folder is locked and to run Clean Up.

Any help with this would be great - I have a file on the server that I can't download that I need to compare with as soon as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `svn` thru the command line? If you did, show the commands you tried!

Comment: No, I'm using Tortoise SVN, I don't know how to use svn via command line.  I basically just know how to commit and update, haha.

Comment: This is probably related to the structure of your particular repo. Hard for us to answer. Contact the maintainer of the repo and get them to sort it out.

Comment: He's out of town until mid-week, and I was hoping to have this done by Monday.  Is there anything you can advise to check for, or is the information I've given not enough data?

Comment: @camdroid: svn from the command line is fairly straightforward. Use `svn co URL` to check out the repository from some URL, `svn status` to find out what's checked in, changed, or not under version control. Use `svn info` to find out information about the current path (like which URL it was checked out from). Use `svn help` to figure out what else you need to do. In your case, change directory to the directory where `tempfile.3.tmp` lives and run `svn status`, you could learn a lot more about what's going on. Figure out what you can, otherwise post your research and the results of `svn status`

Comment: Check if any other app is holding those temp files. You can do it with the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653): Install -> Open it -> Ctrl-F -> Enter 'tempfile' (without quotes) in the edit box -> push 'Search' button.

Answer (score 1):

Are other users of the same repository working from a Unix operating system?

If so, someone might have created two files or directories whose names differ only in case (for example, "Simfile" and "simfile"). Because Windows filesystems are not case-sensitive, this makes the repository impossible to check out on a Windows machine, and results in errors similar to what you describe.

You should be able to use the "Repository Browser" of TortoiseSVN to check if such a case conflict exists. If you find one, it should still be possible to check out or "export" the two clashing files or directories one at a time, placing them in different parent folders. You can also use the repository browser to to fix the clash by renaming one of the two files from the repository browser.